# FTP - user to upload file to different user's directory

Tags: permissions, ftps

I installed `vsftpd` and configured SFTP.

I have a standard user who is named, let's say, `user1` with all perms. I don't want to give the password to my friend. I only want him to access a specific directory to upload files so server can run them.

The file place is : `/home/user1/upload`

I created a user, with no shell login, named `user1ftp`. I changed the user home location to `/home/user1/upload` so when he logs in, he directly logs into the upload directory. He can upload and delete files in it.

The problem is that when he uploads a file, the server cannot run it. His files' permission are: **`rw-r--r--`**

I need to make sure that when he uploads a file, the permissions are **`rwxrwxr-x`**

These users are members of the same group.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 2):

The feature you are looking for is called the *umask*.  That feature removes permissions from a permission-setting.

Setting a *umask* to zero (`0`) turns it completely off.  If you set it to **2**, that will turn off only the "w' flag near the end of the permissions.  According to the discussion (see below), if you do this, `vsftpd` can allow the **`rwxrwxr-x`** that you are trying to achieve.

There are two settings in vsftpd's configuration file (perhaps `/etc/vsftpd.conf`).

- `local_umask` (the one you want)
- `anon_umask` (for anonymous users)

Further reading:

- [How does local_umask and file_open_mode work?](https://superuser.com/questions/441515/how-does-local-umask-and-file-open-mode-work)
- [Default owner/permissions of created files via VSFTPD](https://serverfault.com/questions/201305/default-owner-permissions-of-created-files-via-vsftpd)